# Input fields value is empty after clone

Tags: jquery, html, dom, post

So I'm having a problem with the jQuery Clone function. I have this div with form-elements which I want to add to my form when the user asks for it.

But when I append a cloned input field to the form the input fields value will stay empty. This causes my POST-variable to be unset.

Has anybody any experience with this stuff?

Thanks

EDIT: I tried not using the clone function and did only this code: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6614378/code.png

The code above still gives no real value to my input fields.

Comment: @user1954920 show only relevant code, unless you show your code how are we supposed to tell what's wrong with your code??

Comment: @Sibu the most relevant part can be found here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6614378/code.png

Comment: @Sven if you can post a working demo in http://jsfiddle.net/ , it will be most useful

Comment: @Sibu http://jsfiddle.net/xQBnB/

When you press the button, an inputfield will show up. But the value-attribute will not be filled when typing in the input field

Comment: @Sven when i type all the values stays there..even after pressing button addn no. of times!! which browser are you using

Comment: @Sibu the value will show up in the textfield, but not in the actually value-attribute, which makes it unset in $POST.

Comment: @Sven and why do you want to do that??..all your values will be saved in product array and you have to loop through the array to get values

Comment: @Sibu that's the problem, the product array is empty, so i can't loop through the array..

Comment: @Sven this has to work., can you post code with form.. i will check it

Comment: @Sibu if you go to http://jsfiddle.net/xQBnB/2/ press the button, put something in the newly input field and check the value with firebug/inspector you will find an empty value.

Comment: @Sven check your `post_max_size` in php.ini and make sure the size of the uploaded file is less than that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xQBnB/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var num = 1;
        $('#button').click(function(){
            var toAppend = '<br><input type="text" value="" placeholder="put something in" name="product['+ num +'][name]">';
            $('#product').append(toAppend);
            num++;
        });

      $('#frmsub').click(function(){
        $('input[name^="product"]').each(function(){
          alert($(this).val());
        });
        });

    });
```

As you can see, it has nothing to do with value attribute, whatever value you input in the textbox that will be the value of textbox

*Update 2) Getting the values in php*

```
<form id="product" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="product[0][name]" value="5">
    <input type="hidden" name="multtxt" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name='frmsub' id='frmsub' value='submit'>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['multtxt'])){

    $prod_cnt = $_POST['product'];
    foreach($prod_cnt as $prod)
    echo $prod['name'];


}
?>
```

Comment: yes, now jquery is able to find the value. But the post will still be empty, cause the value-attribute is empty.

Comment: @Sven absolutely wrong,post value will get the same value as i told it nothing has to do with value attribute, if you are using php check my updated answer

Comment: strange, cause when i let the controller check with 'isset' it gives false as answer..